# Do negative weights affect learning when using ReLUs in neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

When we use ReLU as our activation function can we say that negative weights don't have any effect on learning process of the neural network?

Comment: If you draw a graph of ReLU(-x), it should be immediate that negative weights give a *reflection* of the ReLU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative weights do have an effect on the learning process even if you are using ReLU because ReLU only touches neuron outputs, not weights itself.

Let's imagine a situation where you have two input neurons and a single output neuron with a ReLU activation function like in the image below.

[image: reLU]

You can easily compute that even negative weights are important. If you set `w1` to `1` and `w2` to `-1` the output will be equal to `1`, because `3 * w1 + 2 * w2 = 1` and if you aply relu to it the final answer will be still `1`. When you decrease negative value to `-2` and compute the answer `3 * w1 + 2 * w2 = 3 * 1 + 2 * (-2) = -1` after applying relu `relu(-1)` you will get `0`